# How does one change the capitalization of titles?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, capitalization

I have seen many mathematical papers with the following format.
[image: The first format.]

However, I am only able to typeset files of the following type.[image]

The notable differences include the all-caps, boldface title rather than the normally-formatted title and centred text with small caps font for section titles rather than bolded, left-justified text. I figure this must be a format as almost all recently-published papers I've read used it.

I use TeXShop on Mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: The arXiv lets you download the source of most of its papers. That might be a lot easier than asking a series of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Davislor pointed out, you can download the [source](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1709.07343) and see, how it's done. In this case, the document class used is `amsart`, which provides the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\date{\today}


\title{\'Etale cohomology of diamonds}
\author{Peter Scholze}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Motivated by problems on the \'etale cohomology of Rapoport--Zink spaces and their generalizations, as well as Fargues's geometrization conjecture for the local Langlands correspondence, we develop a six functor formalism for the \'etale cohomology of diamonds, and more generally small v-stacks on the category of perfectoid spaces of characteristic $p$. Using a natural functor from analytic adic spaces over $Z_p$ to diamonds which identifies \'etale sites, this induces a similar formalism in that setting, which in the noetherian setting recovers the formalism from Huber's book...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

The aim of this manuscript is to lay foundations for the six operations in \'etale cohomology of adic spaces and diamonds, generalizing previous work of Huber...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do that on ArXiv and on the link you provided; both times, I got the error "Safari can’t open the file “1709.07343” because no available application can open it." Thanks nonetheless. That's all I needed.

Comment: It's a tar file without extension